# Wordpress - Hiding or removing parent theme's templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm producing a child theme for wordpress. I'm trying to make it as fool proof as possible for the end users so would like to remove all the parent's page templates so that they can't be accidentally selected.

Is there a way to de-register them from the child themes functions or plugin? I know I could just go and delete them from the parent but that's not update/upgrade proof.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019-06-10**: At the time of writing this answer there was no good way of doing this, but since then the [`theme_page_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/) and [`theme_templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_templates/) hooks has been added, which makes this possible. From the `theme_page_templates` docs page:

> **Filter page templates by blog id**
>
> Suppose you have the blog `Food` with the id 2 and the template `page-food.php` which should only be used for this blog. The example below removes the page template from dropdowns of other blogs:
>
> ```php
> /**
>  * Filter the theme page templates.
>  *
>  * @param array    $page_templates Page templates.
>  * @param WP_Theme $this           WP_Theme instance.
>  * @param WP_Post  $post           The post being edited, provided for context, or null.
>  * @return array (Maybe) modified page templates array.
>  */
> function wpdocs_filter_theme_page_templates( $page_templates, $this, $post ) {
>     $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
>     $food_blog_id    = 2;
>
>     if ( $current_blog_id != $food_blog_id ) {
>         if ( isset( $page_templates['page-food.php'] ) ) {
>             unset( $page_templates['page-food.php'] );
>         }
>     }
>     return $page_templates;
> }
> add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'wpdocs_filter_theme_page_templates', 20, 3 );>
> ```

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

There are no filters available in `get_themes()` which is where WordPress locates the template files from the theme and parent theme in case one is used. Nor are there any filters available for `get_page_templates()` or `page_template_dropdown()`. I would say your best option is to somehow remove or hide the option elements in the admin panel, preventing the user from choosing them.

Hook onto the `admin_head` action and inject javascript or css to handle `#page_template option[val=template-filename.php]`.

Comment: This answer is no longer true,  as the `theme_page_templates` hook was introduced in WordPress 3.9.0 and the `theme_templates` hook was introduced in WordPress 4.9.6 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_templates/

Answer (score 1):

Simply add empty templates, that have the same name and template header, in your child theme. Then include your own templates from within those template with `locate_template();`.

Comment: Hi Kaiser, that's a nice idea but I'd still have 'Showcase Template' and 'Sidebar Template' visiable in the Admin area which will confuse the (l)users. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question with more answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-to-remove-a-parent-theme-page-template-from-a-child-theme

Note that some answers do not work for later versions of WordPress (like 3.8). WordPress 3.9 might have a hook that will allow developer to simply exclude or rename templates in the list.